# Append a hash to a series of nested hashes in Puppet4

Tags: puppet

Given is an hash of hashes in hieradata:

```
profile::jdbc::connections
  connection_name1:
    username: 'user1'
    password: 'pass1'
  connection_name2:
    username: 'user2'
    password: 'pass2'
```

and an hash of defaults in puppet code:

```
$jdbc_default = {  
  'testWhileIdle'                => true,
  'testOnBorrow'                 => true,
  'testOnReturn'                 => false,
  'timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis'=> '30000',
  'maxActive'                    => '20',
  'maxWait'                      => '10000',
  'initialSize'                  => '5',
  'removeAbandonedTimeout'       => '600',
  'removeAbandoned'              => false,
  'logAbandoned'                 => true,
  'minEvictableIdleTimeMillis'   => '30001',
}
```

How can I add the defaults to each Hash in the connections hash?

Result can also be an array of hashes but a hash with the same keys as in the connection hash would be nice.

Comment: This is not a Ruby question.

Comment: not excactly but yout can derived an puppet solution from a ruby one.

Comment: However it will confuse people who read this in the archives, who might believe that Hashes in Ruby and Puppet are the same.

Comment: ok, I remove the ruby tag

Comment: You also said you provided an Array of Hashes. That is incorrect; your Hiera data is in fact a Hash of Hashes.

Comment: Ta. Also, are you using Puppet 3 or Puppet 4?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147235/discussion-between-christian-meissner-and-alex-harvey).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puppet 4 provides a number of iteration functions that can be used here, but the clearest and easiest solution to understand is probably to use Puppet's `map` and `merge` functions ([ref](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/function.html#map) and [ref](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib)):

```
  $connections = {
    'connection_name1' => {
      'username' => 'user1',
      'password' => 'pass1',
    },
    'connection_name2' => {
      'username' => 'user2',
      'password' => 'pass2',
    },
  }

  $jdbc_default = {
    'testWhileIdle'                => true,
    'testOnBorrow'                 => true,
    'testOnReturn'                 => false,
    'timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis'=> '30000',
    'maxActive'                    => '20',
    'maxWait'                      => '10000',
    'initialSize'                  => '5',
    'removeAbandonedTimeout'       => '600',
    'removeAbandoned'              => false,
    'logAbandoned'                 => true,
    'minEvictableIdleTimeMillis'   => '30001',
  }

  $merged = $connections.map |$k,$v| {
    {$k => merge($jdbc_default, $v)}
  }

  notice($merged)
```

Then check it:

```
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): [{connection_name1 => {username => user1, password => pass1, testWhileIdle => true, testOnBorrow => true, testOnReturn => false, timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis => 30000, maxActive => 20, maxWait => 10000, initialSize => 5, removeAbandonedTimeout => 600, removeAbandoned => false, logAbandoned => true, minEvictableIdleTimeMillis => 30001}}, {connection_name2 => {username => user2, password => pass2, testWhileIdle => true, testOnBorrow => true, testOnReturn => false, timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis => 30000, maxActive => 20, maxWait => 10000, initialSize => 5, removeAbandonedTimeout => 600, removeAbandoned => false, logAbandoned => true, minEvictableIdleTimeMillis => 30001}}]
Notice: Compiled catalog for alexs-macbook-pro.local in environment production in 0.07 seconds
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.01 seconds
```

However, you mentioned that your data comes from Hiera. Therefore, your actual code would look like:

```
class profile::jdbc (
  Hash[String, Hash[String, String]] $connections,
) {
  $jdbc_default = {
    'testWhileIdle'                => true,
    'testOnBorrow'                 => true,
    'testOnReturn'                 => false,
    'timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis'=> '30000',
    'maxActive'                    => '20',
    'maxWait'                      => '10000',
    'initialSize'                  => '5',
    'removeAbandonedTimeout'       => '600',
    'removeAbandoned'              => false,
    'logAbandoned'                 => true,
    'minEvictableIdleTimeMillis'   => '30001',
  }

  $merged = $connections.map |$k,$v| {
    {$k => merge($jdbc_default, $v)}
  }

  notice($merged)
}
```

Note that because Hashes can be added in Puppet, the `merge` function, which comes from stdlib, can be avoided:

```
  $merged = $connections.map |$k,$v| {
    {$k => $jdbc_default + $v}
  }
```

(Note that `{'a' => 1} + {'b' => 2}` returns `{'a' => 1, 'b' => 2}`. If keys are in both, the right-hand side wins, i.e. `{'a' => 1, 'b' => 2} + {'a' => 2}` returns `{'a' => 2, 'b' => 2}`.)

Now, if you require a Hash of Hashes, rather than an Array of Hashes, you can achieve this via the `reduce` function:

```
  $merged = $connections.reduce({}) |$memo, $x| {
    $memo + {$x[0] => merge($jdbc_default, $connections[$x[0]])}
  }
```

or:

```
  $merged = $connections.reduce({}) |$memo, $x| {
    $memo + {$x[0] => $jdbc_default + $connections[$x[0]]}
  }
```

How this works:

`reduce` iterates over each `[key, value]` pair from the Hash. The start value is the empty Hash `{}` that is passed as an argument to `reduce`.

In the first round, `$memo` is set to `{}`, and `$x` is set to the first `[key, value]` pair. The key is, therefore, given by `$x[0]`.

In the subsequent rounds, `$memo` retains the value returned by the expression in the Lambda in the previous iteration, i.e. `$memo + {$x[0] => $connections[$x[0]] + $jdbc_default}`.

Showing this works:

```
Notice: Scope(Class[Profile::Jdbc]): {connection_name1 => {username => user1, password => pass1, testWhileIdle => true, testOnBorrow => true, testOnReturn => false, timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis => 30000, maxActive => 20, maxWait => 10000, initialSize => 5, removeAbandonedTimeout => 600, removeAbandoned => false, logAbandoned => true, minEvictableIdleTimeMillis => 30001}, connection_name2 => {username => user2, password => pass2, testWhileIdle => true, testOnBorrow => true, testOnReturn => false, timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis => 30000, maxActive => 20, maxWait => 10000, initialSize => 5, removeAbandonedTimeout => 600, removeAbandoned => false, logAbandoned => true, minEvictableIdleTimeMillis => 30001}}
Notice: Compiled catalog for alexs-macbook-pro.local in environment production in 0.12 seconds
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.02 seconds
```

Thanks to Henrik Lindberg for explaining this use of `reduce`!

See also the explanation given in the Ruby docs [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce).

On a related note, Henrik mentioned that Puppet 5 will contain a new function, `tree_each`,

> that can iterate over a structure consisting of Array, Hash and Object
>   containers. It can iterate in depth or breadth first order and there
>   are options for controling what to include (containers and/or values
>   and/or include the root of the tree). Other operations can be
>   performed by chaining to other iterative functions for filter and map
>   operations.

The pull request to add this feature is [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/pull/5994).

Comment: your solution creates a array of hashes but how we can create a hash of hashes? $connections.each and a merge inside does not lead to merged hashes.

Comment: Let me think for a while.

Comment: Updated after Henrik Lindberg explained it to me on the Puppet Community Slack.

Comment: The thing about Henrik code is that, while brilliant, it usually has some minor typo somewhere, so be sure to test it out first. Anyway, map does return an array, and `reduce/with` are those two overlooked lambda iterators that can indeed do some interesting things.

Comment: I am not sure there is anyone whose untested code does not have minor typos somewhere! Anyhow, all of the above was tested.

Comment: Great work. It works perfectly an keep complexity away from templates.

Comment: I recommend you add some comments there, because I expect most people will not understand what it does! Good luck.